# HTTP 401 Unauthorized error in sending GetItem Request

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, exchangewebservices, gsoap

I'm using EWS GetItem operation to fetch data from exchange server, but i've got following error

`Error 401 fault: SOAP-ENV:Server[no subcode]
"HTTP Error"
Detail: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

However my login credential are correct, since those are works well with findItem request and response, but when GetItem request goes to server it give above error. My credentials are like:

```
soap *pSoap = proxy->soap;
proxy->soap_endpoint = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
pSoap->userid = "abcd@abcd.onmicrosoft.com";
pSoap->passwd = "abcd1234";
```

And Received log are like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
request-id: b66330dd-37a5-40c0-946f-12a204b2eacb
Set-Cookie: ClientId=OVJLSVEMECIIUMMAXM9JA; expires=Thu, 22-Sep-2016 18:00:57 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-CalculatedBETarget: SG2PR06MB1165.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=fa26578c8e659cf1ccc3f50b3a83; expires=Fri, 23-Sep-2016 18:00:58 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
x-EwsHandler: FindItem
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-DiagInfo: SG2PR06MB1165
X-BEServer: SG2PR06MB1165
Set-Cookie: ClientId=OVJLSVEIIUMMAXM9JA; expires=Thu, 22-Sep-2016 18:00:57 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: SG2PR03CA0031
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 18:00:58 GMT
Connection: close

17d
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="268" MinorBuildNumber="21" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
1e8
</s:Header><s:Body><m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><m:ResponseMessages><m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success"><m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode><m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="2" IncludesLastItemInRange="true"><t:Items><t:Message><t:ItemId Id="
edAQAfAGNvObtNFsAAAA==" ChangeKey="CQfwjm7TRbAAAAAAWl"/></t:Message><t:Message><t:ItemId Id="
133AQAfAGCObtNFsAAAIFUAAAAA==" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACZNImAAAAAWT"/></t:Message></t:Items></m:RootFolder></m:FindItemResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:FindItemResponse>
</s:Body></s:Envelope>


/*  This below log for getItem Request*/

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
request-id: 7a1a654c-fa72-46b0-ab76-a6045c576d9f
Set-Cookie: ClientId=H8THXUH0BECF9HJMTXHEW; expires=Thu, 22-Sep-2016 18:01:01 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: SG2PR03CA0003
WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 18:01:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

What could be possibly wrong here, why one request pass and another fail? any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!, it's error occurs just because of my second request not able to login on the exchange server. since i've provided my credentials only once, So when findItem Response come, connection with the server is 'closed' and my next subsequent request not able to login. so i've to login once again to the server.